# react native FAILURE: Build failed with an exception gradle problem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, development-environment

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'AwesomeProject'.

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not resolve jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1 > org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s

please help how to solve this problem

i tried updating gradle but it didn't worked